# command line to read from stdin or file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

I have a command which runs like this:

```
$ cmd <file_name> [option]
```

The `[option]` is optional and the command can read from `stdin`. So following commands are OK:

```
$ cmd file
$ cmd file option
$ cat file | cmd
```

However, reading from `stdin` with `[option]` gives error:

```
$ cat file | cmd option
Cannot open file: option
```

So how to construct the command, or I have to change the program to read from `stdin` correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't accept a filename as a parameter.  Parse the command line for options only.  If the user wants to read from a file, they can redirect `cmd option < file`

Comment: Can we see the code for cmd?

Comment: The typical pattern is that "options" come first, and are flagged with dashes, and followed by the parameters (i.e. "cat -v file" or "ls -lh dir")  You might want to look at "man getopt".

Comment: Is `option` a simple flag or set of single values (as in Y/N or red/green/blue/black)?  Or is it a set of options (such as -d -f -t, etc.)?  If the latter, could you not add an option to control whether your script looks for a file or gets input from stdin?  (Mind you, this depends heavily on where the file/stdin is being used and what that data looks like.  If you could share what cmd is actually doing, we might be able to help more.

Comment: It's just a single value option. Anyway, just did a quick fix as @WilliamPursell said. Will look for other options suggested by others. Thanks all.

Comment: @WilliamPursell 's redirect idea is probably the best option.  The alternative I came up with is not as clean or simple -- make <file_name> a required parameter, but the users have the option of putting a special value to tell the script to get data from stdin.  Something like `cmd stdin [option]`.  The code would then test for "stdin" and behave accordingly.

Comment: Can you tell the option apart from a file name?  The standard technique is `-o` for an option, or one of the long-form variants (`-option` or `--option`).  And `--` (on its own as an argument) marks the end of options; anything after is a file name.  So, it is normally easiest to follow the standard conventions.  Your command synopsis might become `cmd [-o] [file ...]` (meaning "perhaps a `-o` option, followed optionally by one or more file names).  Using the built-in `getopts` would make that easy.  The further you deviate from the standard, the harder it gets.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2):

1. In `bash`, (and shells like `ksh`, `zsh`, and `yash`...), there's [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), which turns the output of a pipe into an *ad hoc* temporary file in the `/dev/fd/` directory:

   ```
   cmd <(cat file) option
   ```
2. As [R. Sinasohn comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265622/command-line-to-read-from-stdin-or-file/43268944#comment73601969_43265622), something like `/dev/stdin` may work:

   ```
   cat file | cmd /dev/stdin option
   ```

---

Those methods won't be satisfactory if the command depends on a file's being writable, or having proper metadata:

```
# No editors:
sed -i 's/a/A/' <(echo abcd)
sed: couldn't edit /dev/fd/63: not a regular file

# whatever `file` does won't work.
file <(echo abcd)
/dev/fd/63: broken symbolic link to pipe:[15331948]

# file size not the same as data size.
ls -Hlog <(echo abcd)
prw------- 1 0 Apr  6 23:27 /dev/fd/63
```